# How to restore TFS 2015 DB on TFS 2018?

Tags: tfs

I did a pre-production upgrade of TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 on another Windows server. It worked fine. During my TFS 2018 tests developers submitted new code to TFS 2015. Now, I would like to restore the latest TFS 2015 DB on TFS 2018 again and switch all dev's workplaces to TFS 2018. 
Do I need to repeat whole TFS 2018 installation process to upgrade TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 or there is another way of doing this?

If I need to repeat TFS2018 installation, do I need to uninstall TFS 2018  before that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-production upgrade is just a **dry run** of your upgrade in a production environment.

Usually  we use this to test your upgrade. This process test upgrades the databases. You can use this to simultaneously test your TFS 2018 on another hardware while continue to use your existing older TFS up.

Once you are ready for upgrade, **restore the databases again** and just use the **Production Upgrade**  scenario during the server configuration wizard.

Not sure if you would like to restore the latest TFS 2015 DB on TFS 2018 on production environment or pre-production environment.

If you want to restore the newly changes on TFS2015 to pre-production TFS 2018 environment. It's not a common situation, usually we will abandon the pre-production environment. If you insist on this, you may have to re-upgrade to TFS2018 with pre-production style again. You could also try to back up the database on TFS2015 and restore it in TFS2018 pre-production environment. And you may have to change  server IDs which ensures that this deployment will not interfere with the production environment.

Otherwise, suggest you directly move the changes in the production environment later, a [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/12/19/in-place-upgrade-to-tfs-2017-rtw-release-to-web-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/) for In-place upgrade to TFS2017(similar to TFS2018 without sharepoint) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I would like to  restore the refreshed TFS 2015 DB on TFS 2018. The reason is the preproduction environment has upgraded Windows Server 2016 and TFS 2016 whereas production environment is on older versions Windows 2012 and SQL 2008).

Comment: In my understanding, I have to uninstall TFS 2018 in pre-production environment, restore refreshed TFS 2015 DB over there and install TFS 2018 back again in order to switch production environment to pre-production one. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: @MBK Yes, this is the most appropriate way for now,once you are ready to upgrade the hardware, suggest you directly move to production environment from TFS2015 to TFS2018 later.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to uninstall: simply remove the Application Tier configuration. You can do it easily from the Administration Console (screenshot is for removing the Proxy feature, simply what you need).

[image: Remove a feature from TFS]

Comment: Thank you, Giulio. Sorry I cannot mark your response as an answer as I marked Patrick's response as the one already.